# How do I make a full screen in LWJGL?

Tags: java, fullscreen, lwjgl

I am making a game in eclipse with LWJGL and I would like to know how to make the screen go full screen by changing some of the following code. Could you help, please?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    AppGameContainer appgc;
    try{
        appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Game(gamename));
        appgc.setDisplayMode(700, 500, false);
        appgc.start();
    }catch(SlickException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [JavaDoc](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/AppGameContainer.html#setDisplayMode%28int,%20int,%20boolean%29) says that the 3th param of `setDisplayMode` indicates the fullscreen flag. Try putting it on true.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable fullscreen mode by calling `Display.setFullscreen(true);`.

Also, be sure to set display mode with resolution supported in fullscreen mode.

Ref: http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=LWJGL_Basics_5_%28Fullscreen%29

---

Edit: After I've seen your edit (with snippet), you need to call `appgc.setFullscreen(true);` ([doc](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/AppGameContainer.html)).

So it all looks like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    AppGameContainer appgc;
    try {
        appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Game(gamename));
        appgc.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
        appgc.setFullscreen(true);
        appgc.start();
    }
    catch(SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

OR

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    AppGameContainer appgc;
    try {
        appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Game(gamename));
        appgc.setDisplayMode(800, 600, true);
        appgc.start();
    }
    catch(SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: ... before calling `Display.create`. I'm almost certain it doesn't work if you call it afterwards.

Comment: Hello, thank you for you answer but when I do the following code:

Comment: I did you first code and it made a full screen window,but it did not have the close button, minimize button or any others on the top so I had to press control, alt delete to get to task manager to close it down and I had to reset the resolution on my computer every time I reset it.

Comment: I didn't realize you mean "maximizing window" instead of "going fullscreen". Well, I think what you need to do first is attach your `AppGameContainer` to a `Canvas`. Then, maximize the `JFrame` that holds it using `frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`. But I don't know how one would do that with an `AppGameContainer`. If you were using `Display` you could go `setParent(canvas)` (where `canvas` is the canvas you want the game to be painted on).

Answer (score 0):

You have  to search for resolutions wich is available at your display and only at those resolutions are working with fullscreen